# Darle forma a una tabla con bootsrap y html

Tags: html, bootstrap

Hola un pregunta sobre diseño estoy en cero en diseño;
quiero lograr esto en mi tabla `html`

Actualemnte esta asi: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ESTE ES EL RESULTADO FINAL QUE LE QUIERO DAR "SEMAFORO DOCENTE" Y "SEMAFORO ALUMNO" EN LA TABLA

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo de la tabla :

```
<div class="box-body">
    <table id="tabla_asistencias"
        class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover responsive"
            cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                 <th class="text-center">Fecha</th>
                 <th class="text-center">turno</th>
                 <th class="text-center">Total docentes</th>
                 <th class="text-center">Docentes Asistentes</th>
                 <th class="text-center">Docentes faltantes</th>
                 <th class="text-center">Semaforo</th>
                 <th class="text-center">Total alumnos</th>
                 <th class="text-center">Alumnos Asistentes</th>
                 <th class="text-center">Alumnos faltantes</th>
                 <th class="text-center">Semaforo</th>
                 <th class="text-center">fecha registro</th>
                 <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;">Reporte</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
         <tbody>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: ¿Qué forma le quieres dar? Con lo que tienes puesto en la pregunta, no queda muy claro qué es lo que estás buscando hacer (el resultado final). Sé más específico

Comment: ¿Qué más le falta?

Comment: le quiero dar la forma de la imagen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siguiendo el ejemplo de @Franklin'j de esta forma intervienes un poco menos en la tabla que ya tienes hecha:

```
<div class="box-body">
    <table id="tabla_asistencias"
        class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover responsive"
            cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="2">Mostrar... Registros</th>  <!-- En este th va el input para números que tienes -->
                  <th colspan="4" style="text-align:center">Semáforo docente</th>
                  <th colspan="4" style="text-align:center">Semáforo alumno</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <th class="text-center">Fecha</th>
                 <th class="text-center">turno</th>
                 <th class="text-center">Total docentes</th>
                 <th class="text-center">Docentes Asistentes</th>
                 <th class="text-center">Docentes faltantes</th>
                 <th class="text-center">Semaforo</th>
                 <th class="text-center">Total alumnos</th>
                 <th class="text-center">Alumnos Asistentes</th>
                 <th class="text-center">Alumnos faltantes</th>
                 <th class="text-center">Semaforo</th>
                 <th class="text-center">fecha registro</th>
                 <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;">Reporte</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
         <tbody>
       </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Puedes ver como queda [aquí](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LyXEMK#anon-login).

Answer (score 1):

Esto es lo que se me ocurre a mi

```
    <thead>
        <th colspan="2"></th>
        <th colspan="4">Semaforo docente</th>
        <th colspan="4">Semaforo alumno</th>
        <th colspan="2"></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Fecha</th>
            <th class="text-center">turno</th>
            <th class="text-center">Total docentes</th>
            <th class="text-center">Docentes Asistentes</th>
            <th class="text-center">Docentes faltantes</th>
            <th class="text-center">Semaforo</th>
            <th class="text-center">Total alumnos</th>
            <th class="text-center">Alumnos Asistentes</th>
            <th class="text-center">Alumnos faltantes</th>
            <th class="text-center">Semaforo</th>
            <th class="text-center">fecha registro</th>
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;">Reporte</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data1</td>
            <td>data2</td>
            <td>data3</td>
            <td>data4</td>
            <td>data5</td>
            <td>data6</td>
            <td>data7</td>
            <td>data8</td>
            <td>data9</td>
            <td>data10</td>
            <td>data11</td>
            <td>data12</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```